# Change data from second to minutes/hours/days in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have some problem with AmCharts plugin. I have JSON'a who calls me a second. I would like to turn the second in minutes / hours / days (depending on how many there are). There is a some easy way? For example, it looks like this:

```
var dataProvider = [
{title:"Test_1", value:"89"},
{title:"Test_2", value:"43"}
];
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "dark",
  "dateFormats": 'DD:JJ:NN:SS',
  "dataProvider": dataProvider,
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "42%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "legend":{
    "enabled": true,
    "align": "center",
    "color": "white",
    "labelText" : "[[title]]"
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pusbt7ty/)

In the dataProvider I have 'value' which kept seconds. It is a simple method that will turn them to me at another time unit and displays on the graph?

Comment: Do you mean you want the second values that are in data, formatted as time (i.e. 00:15:23) in labels/balloons?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: No one is able to help me? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#balloonFunction) to define your own custom function that formats the balloon. If set the chart passes in the whole information about slice being hovered and expects it to return a string to be displayed in a balloon.

The same way, you could use the [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelFunction) to format labels.

Here's your chart with the `balloonFunction` applied to format second values as time:

```js
var dataProvider = [
  { title: "Test_1", value: "89" },
  { title: "Test_2", value: "43" }
];
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "dark",
  "dateFormats": 'DD:JJ:NN:SS',
  "dataProvider": dataProvider,
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "42%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]",
  "balloonFunction": function(item) {

    function formatTime(seconds) {
      var sec_num = parseInt(seconds, 10);
      var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
      var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }
      var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
      return time;
    }

    return item.title + ": " + formatTime(item.value);
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "align": "center",
    "color": "white",
    "labelText": "[[title]]"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: It is possible to use these functions in the legend to chart?

Comment: Yep. Use legend's `valueFunction` in exactly the same way: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueFunction